# Models with fixed cardinality of non-Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, model-theory

In the usual $\mathsf{ZFC}$, we know that there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ many subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are not (Lebesgue) measurable. On the other hand, the [Solovay model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) also provides us a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ which has $0$ non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know if the following in-between assertion has been established or is currently being researched on:

> For any cardinal $\kappa < 2^\mathfrak{c}$, is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are exactly $\kappa$ non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

If this is false, can we classify the cardinals in which the assertion above holds?

Comment: If $X\subseteq (0,1)$ is a non-measurable subset and $Y\subseteq (1,2)$ is a null set, then $X\cup Y$ is a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ null subsets of $Y$.

Comment: @HanulJeon I was initially skeptical on if having one non-measurable set implies the existence of a bounded non-measurable set, but it is not difficult to obtain one. See my answer below. Thanks/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, $\mathsf{ZF}$ easily proves that if there exists at least one non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then there must be $2^\mathfrak{c}$ non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be non-measurable. Then $X = (X \cap [0,\infty)) \cup (X \cap (-\infty,0)) =: A \cup B$. If both $A$ and $B$ are measurable, then $X$ must also be measurable, at it is a finite union of measurable sets. Thus, we must have that either $A$ or $B$ is non-measurable.

WLOG say $A$ is not measurable. Now there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ measurable sets in $(-\infty,0)$, and for any of such set $C$, we have that $A \sqcup C$ is not measurable. This gives $2^\mathfrak{c}$ distinct non-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm not sure that ZF proves that countable union of (Lebesgue-)measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Wojowu’s objection is warranted, however, countable union is not needed for the argument. ZF certainly proves that the union of *two* measurable sets is measurable, thus if $X$ is non-measurable, then $X\cap[0,+\infty)$ or $X\cap(-\infty,0]$ is non-measurable, and this gives plenty of room to make the argument work.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. With that in mind, is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there exists a non-measurable set but all bounded sets are measurable?

Comment: Thank you. Note that you don’t actually need $C$ measurable: $A\cup C$ is non-measurable for every subset $C\subseteq(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: You can make this much simpler with symmetric differences: if $X$ is a subset of the Cantor set (hence null) then $X\triangle A$ is measurable iff $A$ is.