# Is "There exists an unbounded non-measurable set but no bounded non-measurable set" consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, model-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392820/). We say that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there exists a finite interval $(a,b)$ such that $A \subseteq (a,b)$.

Working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, the existence of a (Lebesgue) non-measurable set (of $\mathbb{R}$) easily implies the existence of a bounded non-measurable set. A proof is as follows - Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be non-measurable. Then $X = \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} X \cap (n,n + 1]$. If all $X \cap (n,n+1]$ are measurable, then $X$ must also be measurable, at it is a countable union of measurable sets ($\mathsf{AC}$ is used here). Thus, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ in which $X \cap (n,n+1] \subseteq (n,n+2)$ is not measurable.

However, it appears to not be so clear if we only work in $\mathsf{ZF}$, since we cannot guarantee that the countable union above is measurable. I also can't seem to see an easy way around choice here. Thus, if we write:

1. $\mathsf{NM}$ as "there exists a non-measurable set".
2. $\mathsf{BNM}$ as "there exists a bounded non-measurable set".
3. $\mathsf{M}_\omega$ as "countable union of measurable sets is measurable".

My questions are (assuming $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$):

> 1. Is $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg\mathsf{M}_\omega$ consistent?
> 2. Is $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{NM} + \neg\mathsf{BNM}$ consistent?

Comment: Did you mean "*non*-measurable" in your title?

Comment: @Wojowu corrected, thank you.

Comment: For 2, let $f:\mathbb R\to(0,1)$ be a diffeomorphism (= smooth with smooth inverse). I suspect image of any non-measurable set by $f$ is non-measurable as well. This is true under AC but I'm not sure if the proof works in ZF. This would show existence of non-measurable set implies existence of bounded such.

Comment: @Wojowu That’s in fact a comment I originally posted on the linked answer, but on further reflection, I don’t think it works without AC. If you cover  $f(X)$ by an open set $U$ whose measure is close to the measure of $f(X)$, the preimage of $U$ may still be much larger than $X$ (unless $f$ is bi-Lipschitz, in which case it can’t have bounded image). Basically, you still need to split the set to countably many pieces and approximate each piece by open sets separately, and it requires countable choice to collect the pieces together.

Comment: As for question 1, it is consistent with ZF that $\mathbb R$ (and therefore every subset thereof) is a countable union of countable (and therefore null) sets. This certainly implies that Lebesgue measure is not $\sigma$-additive; I’m not sure though whether it also implies the existence of a non-measurable set (i.e., $\neg M_\omega$).

Comment: Emil, Wojowu, what's the issue with using $1/x$ as a function from $(1,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ for this? It's enough to consider non-measurable subsets of $(1,\infty)$, after all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The issue is what I wrote in my comment: how do you prove that if $Y\subseteq(0,1)$ is measurable, then $\{1/x:x\in Y\}$ is measurable, other than by splitting $Y$ to infinitely many pieces bounded away from $0$?

Comment: @Emil: Well, it's enough to prove that the function "preserves" the measure of open sets and compact sets, or rather that it changes those measures in a "predictable way". For open sets that's easy. I think it should be the same for compact sets as well.

Comment: There is a theorem (or, in some developments, a **definition**) ... A set $A$ is measurable if and only if $A \cap [a,b]$ is measurable for every $a<b$.  Are you claiming this is cannot be proved in ZF?  Perhaps improve the question by including the definition of "measurable".

Comment: @Asaf This is the point: even with AC, if the function is not Lipschitz, it does *not* preserve the measure of even open sets in a predictable way, as it may map a bounded set to something of infinite outer measure.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: I'm claiming exactly the opposite. I think that Emil and Wojowu question this theorem's validity, though.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I believe the standard definition of Lebesgue measure in this context is as follows. (1) Define the measure of open sets: any such is a countable disjoint union of open intervals (possibly infinite), take the sum of the lengths of the intervals. (2) Define the outer measure $\lambda^*(X)=\inf\{\lambda(U):U\supseteq X\text{ open}\}$. (3) Define $X$ to be measurable if $\lambda^*(Y)=\lambda^*(Y\cap X)+\lambda^*(Y\smallsetminus X)$ for all bounded intervals $Y$ (or possibly a larger collection of $Y$, I’m not sure what is most common in this point).

Comment: Hmm. Though if I take only bounded intervals as test sets as I just wrote, it *should* actually work. I was originally thinking about arbitrary test sets $Y$. So perhaps this part of the definition is a crucial point that needs to be clarified.

Comment: Taking the  @EmilJeřábek definition.  Suppose $X$ is an unbounded nonmeasurable set.  Then there is a bounded interval $Y$ such that $\lambda^*(Y) \ne \lambda^*(Y\cap X)+\lambda^*(Y\smallsetminus X)$.  Therefore, the bounded set $Y\cap X)$ is also nonmeasurable.  In fact, I believe Lebesgue took this definition.

Comment: I think the point is that with $f(x)=1/x$, null sets are mapped to null sets. And $G_\delta$ sets are mapped to $G_\delta$ set. If you are Lebesgue measurable iff you are almost the same as a $G_\delta$ set, that should just go through.

Comment: You need countable choice to show that a measurable set is a difference of a $G_\delta$ set and a null set. And how do you show that $f$ preserves null stes? This is still the same problem.

Comment: @Emil: If $\Bbb R$ is the countable union of countable sets, then the Lebesgue measure is not well-defined since every set is Borel. If you want to talk about coded sets, that's your problem and I will have no part of this discussion, since that's purposefully kneecapping yourself (I'm not saying it's not interesting, it's just too hard to be actually useful).

Comment: The Lebesgue measure may be weird, but why would it not be well defined? I just defined it.

Comment: @Emil: Because why is that *that* definition, or not the one where you complete the Borel measure? You can define a lot of things in a lot of ways, you need to justify why your choice of definition is better or worse.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the Borel measure, and how do you construct it other than taking something like the definition I gave above, restricted to Borel sets?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: “Why *that* definition?” — that kind of question doesn’t usually have a more definitive answer than “because it’s the/a definition that works well for re-developing the theory in the weaker foundation”; and the definition Emil gave is at least somewhat established in the literature on measurability in choiceless settings, suggesting it’s generally accepted as a good one.  If you want to argue for a different definition, the burden of proof is more on you than on Emil.  (Of course, best would be if OP could tell us which definition they have in mind.)

Comment: @Emil: Exactly. You don't. Measures in the context of measure theory are defined to be $\sigma$-additive. If they are not, then they are not called "measures" but "finitely additive measures". This can be excused when working with something like coded Borel sets, where we have a semblance of $\sigma$-additivity in that if we have a sequence of codes, then the sets generated is also coded. But this definition is awful to work with, and there's a reason why we make it abundantly clear that this is "coded Borel sets" and not "Borel sets".

Comment: @Peter: Not in this case. This case is more akin to saying that we are changing the definition of "compact" to mean "indiscrete" because then we can prove in ZF Tychonoff's theorem.

Comment: So .. We have a fine definition (see @EmilJeřábek) for "Measurable set" that makes sense in ZF.  The fact that the collection of such sets is a sigma-algebra may require AC: but that is not required to answer the question in the title.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Whether you have the test sets be bounded intervals or arbitrary $Y \subset \mathbb{R},$ you get equivalent definitions.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Really? At the risk of sounding like a broken record: how do you prove that without countable choice? Note that this would answer question 2 negatively.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Suppose $X$ is measurable against bounded intervals. Assume $Y$ has finite outer measure (otherwise trivial). Fix an open cover $C$ of $Y$ of measure less than $\lambda^*(Y)+\epsilon.$ Finitely many intervals $\{I_k\}_1^n$ in $C$ contain all but $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ of the measure. For each $k \le n,$ choose covers $I_k \cap X \subset C_{1, k}$ and $I_k \setminus X \subset C_{2, k}$ such that $\lambda(C_{1,k})+\lambda(C_{2,k})<\lambda(I_k)+\frac{\epsilon}{2n}.$ The rest is clear.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Oh, I see! Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, and the answer to your second question is no, under any of the multiple definitions of "measurable" in choiceless contexts.

We will prove a theorem relating various measure-theoretic consequences of countable choice.

(ZF) The following are equivalent. Note that  (1)-(6) are about the algebra of subsets of $[0,1]$ which satisfy $\lambda^*(X)+\lambda^*([0,1] \setminus X)=1$ while (7) refers to the algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $\lambda^*([-n, n] \cap X) + \lambda^*([-n, n] \setminus X) = 2n$ for all $n.$

1. Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-additive.
2. A countable union of measurable sets is measurable.
3. A countable union of null sets is measurable.
4. A countable union of null sets is null.
5. Every null set is contained in a null $G_{\delta}$ set.
6. For every measurable set $X,$ there is an $F_{\sigma}$ set $A$ and a $G_{\delta}$ set $B$ such that $A \subset X \subset B$ and $B \setminus A$ is null.
7. Any of the above but for measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Proof:

(1) $\rightarrow$ (2) Clear.

(2) $\rightarrow$ (3) Clear.

(3) $\rightarrow$ (4) Suppose towards contradiction $X_i$ are null sets with $\lambda(\bigcup_{i<\omega} X_i)>0.$ Let $Y_i = \{x+\frac{m}{2^i}: m < 2^i, \exists j < i (x \in X_j)\}$ (note that addition is mod 1) and $Z_i = Y_i \setminus Y_{i-1}.$ In particular, the $Z_i$ are disjoint null sets whose union has positive measure and is closed under translation by dyadic rationals.

For $A \subset \omega,$ let $H_A=\bigcup_{n \in A} Z_n.$ By (3), each $H_A$ is measurable. We will show that for every $A \subset \omega,$ either $H_A$ or $H_{\omega \setminus A}$ has measure 1.

Suppose $H_A$ has positive measure (otherwise $H_{\omega \setminus A}$ has positive measure). Fix $\epsilon>0.$ By Lebesgue density theorem, there is some interval $I$ of length $\frac{1}{2^n}$ such that $\lambda(H_A \cap I) > \frac{1-\epsilon}{2^n}.$ Clearly $H_{A \setminus (n+1)}$ also satisfies this inequality, and is furthermore closed under translation by $\frac{1}{2^n}.$ Thus, $\lambda(H_A) = \lambda(H_{A \setminus (n+1)}) > 1-\epsilon,$ so $\lambda(H_A)=1.$

Since $H_{\omega}$ has measure 1, we see that $[0,1]$ is a countable union of null sets. By (3), every subset of $[0,1]$ is measurable. However, $\{A \subset \omega: H_A \text{ is measure 1} \}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter, so there is a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1],$ contradiction.

(4) $\rightarrow$ (1) Let $X_i$ be measurable sets. Let $U_i$ enumerate the basic open sets. Define $S_n \subset \omega$ recursively by having $i \in S_n$ iff there is $j$ such that $\lambda(U_i \cap X_j \setminus \bigcup_{k<i, k \in S_n} U_k) > \frac{n}{n+1} \lambda(U_i).$ Let $V_n = \bigcup_{i \in S_n} U_i.$ Then $V:=\bigcap_{n < \omega} V_n$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set such that $\lambda(V)=\sup_{n<\omega} \lambda(\bigcup_{i < n} X_i)$ and $V \triangle \bigcup_{i<\omega} X_i$ is null.

(4) $\rightarrow$ (5)  Let $X$ be null. By (4) we can assume $X$ is closed under translation by rational numbers. Let $U$ be an open cover of $X$ of measure less than $\frac{1}{2}.$ We can canonically cover $X \cap [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ with an open set of measure $\frac{1}{2n}$ by considering the least $m$ such that $\lambda(U \cap [\frac{m}{n}, \frac{m+1}{n}])<\frac{1}{2n}.$ We can thus recursively construct open covers of $X$ of measure less than $\frac{1}{2^n}.$

(5) $\rightarrow$ (6) Similarly to in (4) $\rightarrow$ (1), there is a $G_{\delta}$ set $B_1$ with null symmetric difference from $X.$ Let $B_2$ be a null $G_{\delta}$ set containing $X \setminus B_1.$ Then $B:=B_1 \cup B_2$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set with $X \subset B$ and $B \setminus X$ null. We can similarly construct such a $B'$ for $[0, 1] \setminus X$ and set $A = [0, 1] \setminus B'.$

(6) $\rightarrow$ (4) Let $X_i$ be null sets. Let $X=\bigcup_{i<\omega} X_i.$ Consider $Y = \{2^{-i-1}(1+x): x \in X_i\}.$ It is easy to see $Y$ is null, and thus contained in some null $G_{\delta}$ set $Y'.$ Let $U_n$ be a sequence of open sets covering $Y,$ each satisfying $\lambda(U_n)<\frac{1}{n}.$

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $i<\omega.$ Let $n$ be least such that $\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{\epsilon}{4^{i+1}}.$ Then $X_i$ is covered by a translation of $U_n$ scaled up by $2^{i+1},$ which has measure less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}.$ Applying this construction to all $i,$ we get a cover of $X$ of measure less than $\epsilon.$ Thus, $X$ is null.

(7) Finally, it is routine to verify that assertions (1)-(6) collectively prove their generalizations to $\mathbb{R}.$ E.g., one could verify $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0, \infty)$ sends null sets to null sets and measurable sets to measurable sets
using the fact that it's Lipschitz on each $[2^{-n}, 2^n]$ and that $\frac{1}{x}$ sends $G_{\delta}$ null sets to $G_{\delta}$ null sets. $\square$

Thus, $\text{M}_{\omega}$ fails in any model of ZF + "$\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets" since this theory negates (1), providing an affirmative answer to question 1. As for question 2, if $\neg \text{BNM}$ holds, then we immediately have (2), so every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. In particular, all interpretations of "all sets are measurable" are equivalent.

Comment: Aha! This is great! However, I think the last paragraph uses DC... (Raisonnier's Theorem)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais A non-principal ultrafilter is a nonmeasurable set because it violates Lebesgue density. I think Raisonnier's Theorem is that an $\omega_1$-sequence of reals implies there is a nonmeasurable set, which I didn't use.

Comment: You're right! So Lebesgue Density must use CC or DC?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais No, Lebesgue Density is a choiceless theorem. The standard proof doesn't use any choice.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it! Lebesgue Density requires you to fix a notion of measurable?

Comment: Nope, I didn't quite get it. The real issue is that Lebesgue measure doesn't make sense without DC. Your argument just shows that, in this model, if every set is measurable then every set has measure 0.

Comment: In this context, $X \subset [0, 1]$ is measurable if $\lambda^*(X)+\lambda^*([0,1] \setminus X) = 1.$ If $\lambda(X)=m>0,$ then some open cover of $X$ has measure less than $m(1+\epsilon),$ so there has to be some interval in the open cover on which $X$ has $1/(1+\epsilon)$ of the interval's measure.

Comment: Lebesgue measure makes sense in choiceless contexts, but it is only finitely additive.

Comment: Can you show that $\varnothing$ is measurable in this sense?

Comment: Yes, by compactness of the unit interval, which is also choiceless. In any case, see Foreman and Wehrung's "The Hahn-Banach Theorem implies the existence of a
non-Lebesgue measurable set" for a full discussion on choiceless Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Again with this finitely additive nonsense?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If it makes you feel better we can call it "Lebesgue finitely additive measure." Doesn't have the same ring though.

Comment: That paper fixes a definition of $\lambda^\ast$, using sums of lengths of interval covers, but that's fine since we're using "Lebesgue measure" (whatever that ought to mean). But I think we finally found our point of agreement: if $[0,1]$ is a countable union of countable sets then no countably additive extension of the length-of-interval measure on $\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ is total. And countably additive could be replaced by finitely additive and Lebesgue Densitarian?

Comment: Nope. I messed up again. What is the claim here?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais In ZF, "Lebesgue measure" is a finitely additive measure with the definition given above. The claim is that if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, there is a set which is not Lebesgue measurable, giving an affirmative answer to question 1.

Comment: But that's a fixed definition of Lebesgue measure... I'm bummed since I wanted your argument to be more general! That was the genius part in the first place!

Comment: I think the theorem is that if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets and if every set is measurable (in pretty much any decent interpretation of that) then every set of reals has measure zero. So the question is what is "pretty much any decent interpretation of that".

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I think your earlier suggestion is reasonable. That if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, then there is no total isometry-invariant finitely additive probability measure on $\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ which has the Lebesgue density property.

Comment: This answer has been significantly overhauled. The above discussion refers to a previous argument which has been generalized to the (3) $\rightarrow$ (4) in the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer.

The "right" notion of an unbounded set being measurable in ZF is less than clear. Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets. Let $\langle X_n: n<\omega \rangle$ be a partition of $[0, 1]$ into countable sets. Consider $X=\{x+m: n\le m<\omega, x \in X_n\}.$ It's not hard to show that $X$ has infinite outer measure and zero inner measure. Also, responding to a discussion in the comments, $\{\frac{1}{x}: x \in X\}$ is null since it can be written as a union of a countable set and a set of arbitrarily small outer measure. While this set satisfies the definition of measurability Emil provided in the comments, it violates almost everything we expect measurable sets to satisfy.

I think a better definition would be that $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if for all $\epsilon>0,$ there is an open cover $C$ of $X$ such that for all bounded intervals $I,$ the restriction of $C$ to $I$ has measure less than $\lambda_*(X \cap I)+\epsilon,$ though I don't know if there's any literature studying this. Anyway, under this definition, your first question has an affirmative answer as demonstrated by the previous example, and the second question seems nontrivial.

Edit: Actually we need both inner and outer uniformity for this to be a finitely additive measure. Say $X$ is measurable if for all $\epsilon>0,$ there are open sets $U_1, U_2$ such that $X \subset U_1,$ $\mathbb{R} \setminus X \subset U_2,$ and $\lambda(U_1 \cap U_2)<\epsilon.$

Comment: While I agree now that the right definition of measurability should be the one in your edit (which I would prefer to state as: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist open $U$  and closed $F$ such that $F\subseteq X\subseteq U$ and $\lambda(U\smallsetminus F)<\epsilon$), this is not required for finite additivity: $\lambda$ (that is, $\lambda^*$) *is* finitely additive on the algebra of Carathéodory measurable sets as defined in my comments above.

Comment: My comment was referring to my pre-edit definition, which isn’t even closed under complements.